# Angular 2 rc4 with 3.0 router: how to get all route information efficiently

Tags: angular, router

I'm using router 3.0.0-beta.1 on angular 2 rc4.
I'm wondering how to get multiple parts of data on the current route.
I need params, data and URL.

All three of these parts are exposed on the route by observables.
I came up with this messy code and I am wondering if this can be done more efficiently:

```
@Component({
    ...
})
@Injectable()
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.urlSub = this.route.url.subscribe(url=> {
            this.dataSub = this.route.data.subscribe(data=> {
                this.paramsSub = this.route.params.subscribe(params=> {

                    ... logic using all 3 variables: params, data, url

                });
            });
        });
    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: Why is this messy?

Comment: it requires a lot of boiler plating. I did not add every thing: such as the declaration of the urlSub, dataSub and paramsSub subscriptions. And the unsubscription in the ngOnDestroy method.

Comment: Yes, but you could do this one time only in a shared component/service

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are looking for is zipArray. This will wait till having a value from each observable.

(Extract from docs)
zipArray accepts a variable number of Observables as parameters and returns an Observable that emits arrays, each one containing the nth item from each source Observable.

Sample Code

```
var range = Rx.Observable.range(0, 5);

var source = Rx.Observable.zipArray(
  range,
  range.skip(1), 
  range.skip(2)
);

var subscription = source.subscribe(
  function (x) {
    console.log('Next: ' + x);
  },
  function (err) {
      console.log('Error: ' + err);   
  },
  function () {
      console.log('Completed');   
  });

 Next: [0,1,2]
 Next: [1,2,3]
 Next: [2,3,4]
 Completed
```

Comment: Thanks for the example.Would have been nice if you applied the route data in the example, though ;-)   Can I get all relevant data in the "completed" section, or do I need to use the "next" section? Can you add the actual link to the docs you are referring to?

Comment: I leave that small exercise and any Google searches for the keen reader =)